# Timer constructor undefined

Tags: timer, constructor, actionlistener

I'm making a maze related game and I'm now handling the input. (W, A, S, D to move).

My game board class has the following aspect:

```
public class GameBoard extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private Timer timer;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Board;
    Maze M;
    Hero H;

    public GameBoard() {
        Game A = new Game();
        M = A.getMaze();
        H = A.getHero();
        Board = A.getMaze().getBoard();
        addKeyListener(new AListener());
        setFocusable(true);
        timer = new Timer(25, (ActionListener) this);
        timer.start();
    }
```

But this won't compile:

```
timer = new Timer(25, (ActionListener) this);
timer.start();
```

because of these errors:

> The constructor Timer(int, (ActionListener) this);
>
> The method start() is undefined for the type Timer.

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure as how the timer works and is really for, even though I know it has to do with the user input (and how often it can be "listened"), which is why my program doesn't do anything whenever I type w, a, s or d, during the runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a `java.util.Timer` instead of a `javax.swing.Timer`.